# jQuery Validation 4 fields but only required to fill in one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

How do I validate in case when where I have 4 fields and only 1 is required. I want the pop up alert message to come up only when all 4 of the fields are left blank when user tries to save form. 
My html looks like this.

```
 <input id="txtWorkPhone" name="txtWorkPhone" data-role="maskedtextbox" required="required" data-mask="(999)-000-0000" class="k-textbox phoneInput"/>

<input id="txtHomePhone" name="txtHomePhone" data-role="maskedtextbox" data-mask="(999)-000-0000" class="k-textbox phoneInput" required="required" />
<input id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" maxlength="260" required="required" class="k-textbox standardInput" style="width: 54%;"  />
<input id="txtCellPhone" name="txtCellPhone" data-role="maskedtextbox" required="required" data-mask="(999)-000-0000" class="k-textbox phoneInput" />
```

As you can see I marked all the fields are required.. So how should i go about the validation of these fields ?

Comment: can you show us a jsfiddle of an example?

Comment: I am not sure how to move forward... I did read few articles on creating rules but I can't seem to find a way to implement them.

Comment: You want if your all 4 fields are empty then pop up should show if any field contains value it should now show pop up right?

Answer (score 0):

You can do custom validation as I did. Please check.

```js
$('#submit').click(function () { 
    var allFilled = true;
    $(':input:not(:button)').each(function(index, element) {    
        if (element.value === '') {
            allFilled = false;
        }
    });

    alert(allFilled);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
<input id="txtWorkPhone" name="txtWorkPhone" data-role="maskedtextbox"  data-mask="(999)-000-0000" class="k-textbox phoneInput"/>

<input id="txtHomePhone" name="txtHomePhone" data-role="maskedtextbox" data-mask="(999)-000-0000" class="k-textbox phoneInput"  />
<input id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" maxlength="260"  class="k-textbox standardInput" style="width: 54%;"  />
<input id="txtCellPhone" name="txtCellPhone" data-role="maskedtextbox"  data-mask="(999)-000-0000" class="k-textbox phoneInput" />
<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

On a button click you can simply do this:-

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var isEmpty = $('input[required]').filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value).length > 0
    }).length == 0;

    if (isEmpty) {
        alert('Empty');
    } else {
        alert('Valid');
    }
});
```

Now here:-

```
$('input[required]').filter(function () {
     return $.trim(this.value).length > 0
})
```

Checks for all the inputs having some data entered in it. Next if that `.length == 0;` that means all of the inputs are empty. If that value is greater than 0 that means atleast one of the inputs out of 4 have some value.

Hope it helps!

Comment: so this will check for all the required fields i have on my form?

Comment: @HereToLearn_ yes, incase you want to make it specific to these 4 inputs only than you can use a class instead inplace of `$('input[required]')` to `$('.phoneInput')`.

Comment: Yes , I want this validation only for these 4 inputs. So I will have to define a class in all 4 of my elements ?

Comment: @HereToLearn_ yes, you can add a demo class to all the fields that needed for validation and it would work fine.

Comment: I see what you are saying but I am already using class attribute for the css class that these fields use.

Comment: what would you do in that case ?

Comment: @HereToLearn_ just add the demo class name inside the existing classes like `class="k-textbox phoneInput demoClassName"`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form onsubmit="myFunction()">
 <input id="txtWorkPhone" name="txtWorkPhone"   data-role="maskedtextbox" required="required" data-mask="(999)-000-0000" class="k-textbox phoneInput"/>

<input id="txtHomePhone" name="txtHomePhone" data-role="maskedtextbox" data-mask="(999)-000-0000" class="k-textbox phoneInput" required="required" />
<input id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" maxlength="260" required="required" class="k-textbox standardInput" style="width: 54%;"  />
<input id="txtCellPhone" name="txtCellPhone" data-role="maskedtextbox" required="required" data-mask="(999)-000-0000" class="k-textbox phoneInput" />
 </form>
 <script>
 function myfunction()
 {
     if($(#txtWorkPhone).value() === '' && if($(#textHomePhone).value() === '' && if($(#txtEmail).value() === '' && if($(#txtCellPhone).value() === '')
     {
        // do whatever.
     }
 }
 </script>
```